# Android sinch full screen issue

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

How do I set the remote view of sinch to full screen in Android.

I have try VideoController.setResizeBehaviour,but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use Sinch serverice class. Sinch documentation not properly written.

Put this in public class SinchService extends Service.

```
  mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(new MySinchClientListener());
            mSinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new SinchCallClientListener());
            mSinchClient.getVideoController().setResizeBehaviour(VideoScalingType.ASPECT_FILL);
            mSinchClient.start();
```

Comment: Did you ever tried to hide icons for on going calls ?

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same problem some time ago. Now, I have solution and it is so simple.
Where you are creating sinch client in SinchService insert below code.

```
mSinchClient.getVideoController().setResizeBehaviour(VideoScalingType.ASPECT_FILL);
```

when you try to set **setResizeBehaviour** function anywhere then the error tells clearly that sinchClient is already created, set it before.

I hope, it will help you and others.